# Синхронизация данных нескольких баз данных SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, база-данных, репликация

Есть несколько БД одинаковой структуры с разными данными (из SSMS 2016, если это имеет значение). Необходимо скопировать все данные из них в новую БД, которая будет содержать все существующие и будущие данные из остальных.

Я пытался достичь данного с помощью репликации слиянием, благо её фильтры это именно то, что здесь нужно, однако мне не дает продвинуться тот факт, что все 3 типа репликации сначала удаляют старые данные, а только затем инициализируют двустороннюю синхронизацию.

Я поставил свойству статьи "Действие, если имя уже используется" значение "Удалить данные. Если статья имеет фильтр строк, удалить только данные, соответствующие критерию фильтра.", агент слияния стал ругаться с ошибкой "Не удается распространить скрипт схемы "Unit_2.sch" на подписчика."

Я думал, что дело в разной структуре, но единственные два различия заключаются в столбце rowguid, который создание публикации создает автоматом, и в свойстве "Опубликован слиянием" (серого цвета).

Помогите пожалуйста, как мне настроить эту репликацию?